# neo4j cypher query optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With 500,000 nodes I'm getting 10-15 seconds, any idea how I can optimize this?

start n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.score) RETURN n, n.score ORDER BY n.score DESC Limit 5;

from looking around I get the sense that the WHERE clause is slowing it down but I'm not sure how I can use a MATCH on a property of a node.

Answer (score 1):

As Luanne says it takes time because your are searching in all the nodes of your graph.
You could search only in the nodes that has a score property (by indexing them, by searching them from a common node, or - if you're using Neo4j 2 - by labeling them)

See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html for further explanations on indexes (which seems to be the more common solution).

Comment: I'd pretty much be indexing all the nodes because so many have a score property so I'm not sure if indexing would make it any faster.

Comment: Even if there are many nodes, indexing will make it faster. The problem is that indexing makes the database bigger. Anyway, no matter what kind of database you use (I mean graph or not), the more entities you have, the more it will take time to find one.

Try to index it and give us a feedback, but the problem you're exposing is no more about Neo4j I think.

Answer (score 0):

With node(*) you're effectively touching your entire graph of 500,000 nodes to check the presence of a property, and the ordering the results. How many rows do you get back?
If you drop your order clause is it any faster?

And what's your use case? Wondering if you can model this differently to avoid a global graph operation. For example, index nodes with the score property, or create a relation from all nodes with the score property to some sort of reference node. Depends on your use case really

Comment: The majority of the nodes have a score value. The use case here is to find X nodes with the highest score which is why I used the order. Perhaps when I go to set the score property on each node I should do a comparison with the current set of high scores and make a high score relationship to an indexed high score node, does limit myself a little though.

Comment: Hmm if majority of your nodes have a score value then this is going to be an expensive operation especially as your graph grows. Might have to think of some other ways to handle this outside the graph if it becomes a limiting factor